# Run Octave within the same Terminal session

Tags: macos, terminal, octave

I set an `alias` in my `.bash_profile` for Octave

```
alias octave="open /Applications/Octave.app"
```

It opens in a new Terminal window. How do I run Octave within the same Terminal session like Python does?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it:

```
alias octave = "/Application/Octave.app/Contents/Resources/bin/octave"
```

Answer (score 1):

Your mileage may vary, but I just installed Octave via homebrew

`$ brew install homebrew`

...and it actually worked. It failed once, and I had to manually `brew install gfortran` but then everything came together nicely.

I had tried this a year ago and it was very painful and I ended up using the bundled .app version like you (and made an alias exactly like the one you came up with), but now installing from source seems to have worked great. Plus, it gives you more options for plotting besides gnuplot.